# iOS Push notification in Flutter by Firebase

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification

Please tell me an example or guide version of push notification based on firebase in flutter ios.

I implemented Android, but iOS is not working well
The official firebase guide came out so simple that I don't know :(

- Official Guide-
  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/client?hl=ko

I referred to the official guide, and it was hard, so I followed it after watching the YouTube video, but the alarm didn't come out

I would appreciate it if you could recommend the latest guide.

Additionally, I wonder why I can't receive messages on iOS.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0zGEbiDJcQ